# How to redirect to third party url from Servlet with some hidden parameters

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have requirement to call my third party website (MoneyPayment) with some parameters. I need to use only JSP and Servlet. What I am trying is on submitting the form, I am calling Servlet in which I am trying:

```
pRequest.setAttribute("gatewayparam",vGateparam);
pRequest.setAttribute("checksum", vChecksum);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = pRequest.getRequestDispatcher("https://MoneyPaymentURL");
try {
    dispatcher.forward( pRequest, pResponse );
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.info("IOException-: "+e);
}
```

This is giving me FileNotFoundException:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /ProjectName/https:/MoneyPaymentURL
```

I tried to use send.redirect(URL) as well but in that case how to pass paramters?

Someone please suggest me how to move forward.

Comment: Can you not have the extra values as hidden fields on your form?

Comment: What is your purpose of sending parameters? Do you want to redirect your users to the third party website? Or do you want to send data and process it internally?

Comment: @Jay The payment gateway expects these parameters. We can't ask the gateway team to get these parameters from the Session as they are not going to change anything from there side. We send to just send these parameters as hidden parameters.

Comment: @rumit you still didn't answer my question. Do you want to redirect your users to the payment gateway? Or do you want to just post the data there?

Comment: @rumit , pls check my answer, you can't send POST hidden parameters by using sendRedirect

Comment: @ScaryWombat : Yes I can but my flow is : User selects a check box for payment and click Submit. Now on submit I am calling Servlet which creates the Gateway URL and other parameters which I need to pass to the gateway. In this way how to pass extra values as Hidden fields?

Comment: @rumit clearly speaking now. Do you want your users to be redirected to the payment gateway?

Comment: @Jay Offcourse I need to redirect the user to the payment gateway else what is the use of Payment Gateway.?

Comment: @rumit Now the main concern is... Do you really want to do it on the server? You could have done that with using simple JavaScript.

Comment: @YeWin: Then how to pass extra params.Gateway team is not going to take the params from Session. That's the requirement.

Comment: @Jay: Actually I need to first call the client to fetch the Gateway URL and other extra params which I need to pass while redirecting the user. So in that case I have to call the client.

Comment: @rumit have you heard of AJAX?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect request from a filter to desired servlet with post DataParameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527745/how-to-redirect-request-from-a-filter-to-desired-servlet-with-post-dataparameter)

Comment: @Jay Yes I know AJAX..but in that case it will be security violation because if I written the other extra params in JSON..then those will be visible in Firebug/browser console.

Comment: @Jay how this question is duplicate of the one which you provided in the link?

Comment: @rumit you can use JS to send POST redirects as well. And that could be a dupe as you want to redirect with some parameters that you don't want to show (even in the browser's address bar). Using `response.sendRedirect("...")` does not simply lets you pass parameters with actually hiding them. You could just write a small script that creates a form that *posts* data to the payment gateway.

Comment: @Jay Thanks Jay. I tried this approach and it worked. Thanks!!

Comment: @rumit I am glad that it worked out. Source: **I have developed my own payment gateway recently ;)**

Answer (score 2):

In order to redirect to third party URL from Servlet you should use `response.sendRedirect("theURL")`

- You can pass parameters in the URL as queryString

  - Example: `response.sendRedirect("theURL?paramName=paramValue")`
  - This will not be hidden parameter, will be visible in URL bar
- You can set parameter as `session` attributes

  - Example:
    `session.setAttribute("paramName", "Parameter Value");`
    `response.sendRedirect("theURL");`
  - Get the session attributes in your JSP
    `out.println(session.getAttribute("paramName").toString());`
    `session.removeAttribute("paramName");`

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to use send.redirect(URL) as well but in that case how to pass paramters?** 
Yes, you can't send the `POST` request parameter by using `send.redirect(URL)` but you can you the session attribute to pass the parameter.

**Eg:**

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

session.setAttribute("gatewayparam",vGateparam);
session.setAttribute("checksum", vChecksum);

response.sendRedirect("https://MoneyPaymentURL");
```

So you can get the session value in your new third party website by related usage. By using `scriptlets` or `JSTL`, etc...